# Dynamic Loop, dot-walk variables each time through loop

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I have a script that requires variable dot walking if criteria isn't met.

Each user is assigned to a "Department" on their record. Our department has a tree structure, so the Department that a user assigned to, could be several levels deep of its overall "Parent" Department. My script needs to take the users department, then climb up the tree to see if it's a part of a specific overall "Parent" department. If there's a match, I need to break the loop and display the Department, otherwise, it needs to climb up the tree.  If it reaches the top of the tree and there isn't a match, then I use the original department name.

In my current code, I can account for 3 levels deep, but there may be a need to dynamically look much lower.

```
var dept1 = new DepartmentUtils().getParentDepartment(current.department.sys_id);
var dept2 = new DepartmentUtils().getParentDepartment(current.department.parent.parent.sys_id);
var dept3 = new DepartmentUtils().getParentDepartment(current.department.parent.parent.parent.sys_id);

if(!JSUtil.nil(dept1))
{
    retVal = dept1;
}
else if(!JSUtil.nil(dept2))
{
    retVal = dept2;
}
else if(!JSUtil.nil(dept3))
{
    retVal = dept3;
}
else
{
    retVal = current.department.name;
}
```

Essentially, I was thinking I need to start at the current department level, see if it is a particular name, if not, then look at it's parent name, compare that, and then repeat until I reach the top (where parent is empty).

My problem is I don't know how to handle the dot walking. I tried using the ".parent".repeat(x) command, but I"m not sure if that's the proper route.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to repeatedly access the `.parent` property of a department. If nothing is found on that level, reassign `department` to the next `.parent`:

```
let { department } = current;
while (department) {
  const { sys_id } = department;
  if (!JSUtil.nil(sys_id)) {
    return sys_id;
  }
  department = department.parent;
}
// the above loop will exit once no more nested `.parent` property exists
// so, return the original department name:
return current.department.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have data structure something like this

```
var current = {
    department: {
        parent: {
            sys_id: "parent_1",
            parent: {
                sys_id: "parent_2",
                parent: {
                    sys_id: "parent_3",
                    parent: {
                        sys_id: "parent_4"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can define a recursive function for searching data in a tree.

```
function searchParentDepartment(target_sys_id, fromDepartment){

    //Found matched department
    if(fromDepartment.sys_id === target_sys_id) return fromDepartment;

    if(!!fromDepartment.parent){
        //Has parent, search parent recursively
        return searchParentDepartment(target_sys_id, fromDepartment.parent);
    }else{
        //No parent return null
        return null;
    }
}

var resultDepartment = searchParentDepartment(target_sys_id, current.department);

if(resultDepartment == null){
    resultDepartment = current.department;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually attempted a different approach and it seems to be working. I created a function to loop through each time to check and see if the current sys_id matched one of 3 specific sys_ids.  If so, then display that name, otherwise, check the parent, etc.

```
var dept1 = new DepartmentUtils().getParent(current.department.sys_id);

getParent: function(request)
{
    var parent_name = '';
    var current_name = request;
    var lookup= new GlideRecord('cmn_department');

    lookup.addQuery('sys_id', current_name);
    lookup.query();
    if(lookup.next())
    {

        if(lookup.sys_id == 'xxxxxxx' || lookup.sys_id == 'yyyyyyyy' || lookup.sys_id == 'zzzzzzzzzz')
        {
            return current_name;
        }
        else{

            current_name = lookup.parent.sys_id;
            parent_name = getParent(current_name); // this is recursive functionality the function will get call until last most parent record find        
        }
    }
    if(!JSUtil.nil(parent_name))
    {
        return parent_name; // It will return most parent record
    }
    else
    {
        return current_name; // If we don't have any parent it will return what you passed in parameter above to call function
    }
},
```